# Backbone.js: Should .render() and .remove() be able to reverse each other?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, architecture, backbone.js

Because Backbone.js is pretty flexible, I am wondering about the best approach for certain things. Here I'm wondering if I'm supposed to build my application's views so that '.render()' and '.remove()' correctly reverse each other.

At first, the way that seems cleanest is to pass the view a ID or jQuery element to attach to. If things are done this way though, calling '.render()' will not correctly replace the view in the DOM, since the main element is never put back in the DOM:

```
App.ChromeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    // Instantiate some "sub" views to handle the responsibilities of
    // their respective elements.
    this.sidebar = new App.SidebarView({ el: this.$(".sidebar") });
    this.menu = new App.NavigationView({ el: this.$("nav") });
  }
});

$(function() {
  App.chrome = new App.ChromeView({ el: $("#chrome") });
});
```

It seems preferable to me to set it up so that .remove() and .render() are exact opposites:

```
App.ChromeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    this.$el.appendTo('body');
    this.sidebar = new App.SidebarView({ el: this.$(".sidebar") });
    this.menu = new App.NavigationView({ el: this.$("nav") });
  }
});

$(function() {
  App.chrome = new App.ChromeView();
});
```

What does the Backbone.js community say? Should .remove() and .render() be opposite sides of the same coin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer that `render` does NOT attach the view's element to the dom. I think this promotes loose coupling, high cohesion, view re-use, and facilitates unit testing. I leave attaching the rendered element to a container up to either the router or a main "layout" type container view.

The nice thing about `remove` is that it works without the view having knowledge of the parent  element, and thus is still loosely coupled and reusable. I definitely don't like to put random DOM selectors from my layout HTML (`#main` or whatever) into my views. Definitely bad coupling there.

I will note that in certain annoying situations, some things like the [chosen jQuery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) require some code to run AFTER the element has been attached to the DOM. For these cases I usually implement a `postAttach()` callback in the view and try to keep the amount of code there as small as possible.

Comment: Hmm... How do I undo my .remove() then? Is there an .add() that I should implement, or am I overthinking this? I'm thinking about use cases like lightboxes, notifications, and other UI elements that will add themselves to the dom when they're used and remove themselves when they're done.

Comment: I like this approach more than my own. Use my one only in extrem cases, for the rest use this _not-coupling_ solution

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe (as @PeterLyons sais) you can invoke the `NotificationView` from an external component, `NotificationView.el` will be an anonymous element auto-generated by the `View` it self and the external component is the one that will attach the `NotificationView.el` to the DOM, so `NotificationView.remove()` can be called without problems.

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe have you considered doing show/hide with jQuery instead of remove/render? Not sure exactly what your circumstances are but that might do the trick.

Comment: @PeterLyons show hide is a good option, but sometimes (usually?) I want to re-render the thing on the next show anyway. (use case might be a singleton lightbox, where there can only ever be one on the screen at a time, but it can show lots of different things inside of itself). Would you do a hide, and then a render, and then a show? I guess that would work, it just seems unclean to leave the old markup in the dom hidden when I know I'm likely to change it when I display it again.

Comment: @fguillen I'll have to learn about NotificationView, I don't know what that is.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot that NotificationView was an object from my example, thought it was part of Backbone.

Comment: So I think after reading through this a second time, two thoughts occur to me. #1: The Peter Lyons sentiment is exactly the right one, for reusability reasons. The downside is that this (I think) requires the calling component to both instantiate and render the component as two steps. #2: It seems like the framework could make using views simpler if it allowed for something like what I have in my answer, where there's an optional DOM element param and it auto renders on instantiation if that DOM element is passed in.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the in-house `View.remove()` is very *agressive*.

For the propose of re-create the View again using an external `el` I am used to rewrite it like this:

```
remove: function(){
  this.$el.empty();
  return this;
}
```

But I don't think the framework should implement *magic* behavior to avoid this *external DOM elements deletion*.

This framework behavior is aggressive, ok, but it is very cheap to customize it when needed as we see above.

Comment: I was just about to suggest this. This seems ideal. Is it too much magic-figuring-out/unexpectedness to have the framework detect whether it was sent a dom element or not and either empty the the pre-existing dom element or remove itself? It's really just "put things back the way they were".

Comment: It seems like the only solution is either overriding .remove or implementing one's own .derender

Answer (score 0):

What about this? If we just have .initialize and .render take a parentSelector property, we can do this and end up with a usage that is:

- Loosely coupled
- Reversable .remove()/.render()
- Single method
  instantiation & rendering for the calling method

eg:

```
// Bootstrap file
curl(['views/app']).then(
    function(App){
        app = new App('body');
    });



// view/app.js
   define([
        'text!views/app.tmpl.html'
    ,   'link!views/app.css'
    ]
,   function (template) {

    var App

    // Set up the Application View
    App = Backbone.View.extend({
        // Standard Backbone Methods
        initialize: function (parentSel) {
            console.log('App view initialized')
            if (parentSel) { this.render(parentSel) }
        }
    ,   render: function (parentSel) {
            if (parentSel) { this._sel = parentSel } // change the selector if render is called with one
            if (!this._sel) { return this } // exit if no selector is set

            this.$el.appendTo(this._sel)

            this.$el.html(
                this.compiledTemplate({ 'content':'test content' })
            );
            return this
        }
        // Custom Properties
    ,   compiledTemplate: _.template(template)
    })

    return App
});


// External usage
// I can call .remove and .render all day long now:
app.remove()
app.render()
app.remove()
```

Comment: If you just want the view to toggle between visible and not, doing show/hide is more efficient and more directly expressive of your intent I think. No need to re-render the template every time, for example. But that said, what you have here seems reasonable as well.